# Is the sentence "There are to many cereal in my bowl" correct English

Tags: american-english

Is the sentence "There are too many cereal in my bowl" correct English. What I mean is that I poured too much cereal. Can I say "too many cereal?" My wife says it should be too MUCH cereal.

Who is right?

Comment: Too *much* (non-count noun).

Comment: Just looked up `non-count noun`. I am still lost. lol

Comment: Your wife, of course.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun). And [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mass_noun).

Comment: And *definitely* [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cereal is uncountable noun. 
So, correct is "too much".
https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Never heard of a `non-count noun` before today. Is that sad for a person with a Master degree? lol

Comment: @Sedrick haha! no, it happens sometimes. I have inserted a link. please read.

Comment: @Sedrick Well, that depends on what type of master's it is.

Comment: Computer Science and a BS in Mathematics. My wife has a Ph.D. in Business. She does a lot of research and writing so I went into this not feeling good about it.